# Tipos diferentes de dicionarios python

Tags: python, dicionário

Existe alguma maneira de converter este dicionario:

```
d = {'Ano; Dia; Mes' : '1995; 2; 5'}
```

para este formato:

```
d = {'Ano': '1995'; 'Dia' : '2'; 'Mes': '5'}
```

Obrigado

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Primeiro eu pego as chaves ( `d.keys()` ) e transformo em uma lista, depois eu pego o primeiro elemento ( de valor `0`, `'Ano; Dia; Mes'` ) e os separo a partir de `"; "`

ficando uma lista : `['Ano', 'Dia', 'Mes']`.

Depois eu faço o mesmo com os valores ( `d.values()` ).

Então depois eu coloco esses valores dentro do dicionário usando o `for`.

Ficou meio confuso, mas dá pra entender...

**Ficando assim:**

```
d = {'Ano; Dia; Mes' : '1995; 2; 5'}
d2 = {}

chaves = list(d.keys())
valores = list(d.values())

chaves = chaves[0].split('; ')
valores = valores[0].split('; ')

for i in range(len(chaves)):
    d2[chaves[i]] = valores[i]

print(d2)
```

**Saída**:

```
>>> {'Ano': '1995', 'Mes': '5', 'Dia': '2'}
```

Comment: Era isto mesmo que precisava! Obrigado :)